# SMTPMessage - Delivery Notification Status working strangely

Tags: java, spring, smtp, jakarta-mail

I was trying to get the delivery notification while sending emails using spring mail.

If i give correct **'to'** email address. It works fine. I gets success delivery notification msg.

When i gives incorrect **'to'** email address, I was getting success delivery msg and failure delivery msg.

Why it was returning success msg with failure?
Anything wrong in my code?

```
public class MailSender {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(MailSender.class);

@Autowired
private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

public void sendEmail(FormData formData)
        throws AuthenticationFailedException, MessagingException {
        final Data data = formData.getData();
        MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();   
                 
        MimeMessageHelper msgHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);
        msgHelper.setFrom(data.getFrom());
        msgHelper.setTo(data.getTo());
        msgHelper.setSubject(data.getSubject());
        msgHelper.setText(data.getBody());

        SMTPMessage smtpMessage = new SMTPMessage(message);
        smtpMessage.setReturnOption(SMTPMessage.RETURN_HDRS);
        smtpMessage.setNotifyOptions(SMTPMessage.NOTIFY_DELAY|SMTPMessage.NOTIFY_FAILURE|SMTPMessage.NOTIFY_SUCCESS);            
        javaMailSender.send(smtpMessage);


<bean id="javaMailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="${mail.host}" />
    <property name="port" value="25" />
    <!-- <property name="username" value="${mail.username}" />
    <proprty name="password" value="${mail.password}" />  -->

    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">false</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

---

Success Msg:

> Subject: Relayed: sample mail from local instance Delivery to these
> recipients or groups is complete, but no delivery   notification was
> sent by the destination server:
>
> myalerts@mail.com

---

Failure Msg:

> Subject: Undeliverable: sample mail from local instance
>
> Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:
>
> myalerts@mail.com
> A problem occurred during the delivery of this message to this e-mail address. Try sending this message again. If the problem continues, please contact your helpdesk.

Note: myalerts@mail.com is the wrong mail address to test failure Delivery Notification.
Email functionality is working fine. I was looking just for Delivery Notification

Comment: can you give us examples of actual output?

Comment: new to the forum.so not good at formatting.. please don't downvote

Comment: OK so this tells us what you are expecting, now show us what you are actually getting

Comment: @MoH. I was getting the same thing, but getting both success and failure delivery mails. I should get success notification when email is an valid one and failure notification to invalid email address. But it's not happening.

Comment: Ok, then can you please include the code that deals with sending these errors specifically, the code you provided doesn't seem to help us with your problem. Unless i'm missing something

Comment: @MoH.That is the complete code which i was using to send the email.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting success and failure notifications because you asked for both when you set the notify options.  If you're getting success and failure notifications from **your** mail server for the **same** message, you'll need to ask your mail server vendor why that's happening.